# Ошибка FileNotFoundError в Jupyter

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, jupyter-notebook

Скопировал код из книги по машинному обучению, но когда пытаюсь обратиться к набору данных, то выходит ошибка, что файл не найден.

Функция для скачивания набора данных:

```
import os
import tarfile
from six.moves import urllib
DOWNLOAD_ROOT = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml2/master/"
HOUSING_PATH = os.path.join("datasets", "housing")
HOUSING_URL = DOWNLOAD_ROOT + "datasets/housing/housing.tgz"
def fetch_housing_data(housing_url=HOUSING_URL, housing_path=HOUSING_PATH):
    if not os.path.isdir(housing_path):
        os.makedirs(housing_path)
    tgz_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.tgz")
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(housing_url, tgz_path)
    housing_tgz = tarfile.open(tgz_path)
    housing_tgz.extractall(path=housing_path)
    housing_tgz.close()
```

Функция для загрузки данных:

```
def load_housing_data(housing_path = HOUSING_PATH):
csv_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.csv")
return pd.read_csv(csv_path)
```

Попытка показать первые 5 рядов данных:

```
housing = load_housing_data()

housing.head()
```

Выходит ошибка:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-01b6b4e3c8b2> in <module>
----> 1 housing = load_housing_data()
      2 
      3 housing.head()

<ipython-input-17-d307253a638f> in load_housing_data(housing_path)
      3 def load_housing_data(housing_path = HOUSING_PATH):
      4     csv_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.csv")
----> 5     return pd.read_csv(csv_path)
```

Comment: Проверьте что за путь получился в csv_path, совпадает ли он с реальным путем к файлу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pd.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) умеет парсить данные по URL:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin

url = urljoin(DOWNLOAD_ROOT, "datasets/housing/housing.csv")

df = pd.read_csv(url)
```

результат:

```
In [104]: df
Out[104]:
       longitude  latitude  housing_median_age  total_rooms  total_bedrooms  population  households  median_income  median_house_value ocean_proximity
0        -122.23     37.88                41.0        880.0           129.0       322.0       126.0         8.3252            452600.0        NEAR BAY
1        -122.22     37.86                21.0       7099.0          1106.0      2401.0      1138.0         8.3014            358500.0        NEAR BAY
2        -122.24     37.85                52.0       1467.0           190.0       496.0       177.0         7.2574            352100.0        NEAR BAY
3        -122.25     37.85                52.0       1274.0           235.0       558.0       219.0         5.6431            341300.0        NEAR BAY
4        -122.25     37.85                52.0       1627.0           280.0       565.0       259.0         3.8462            342200.0        NEAR BAY
...          ...       ...                 ...          ...             ...         ...         ...            ...                 ...             ...
20635    -121.09     39.48                25.0       1665.0           374.0       845.0       330.0         1.5603             78100.0          INLAND
20636    -121.21     39.49                18.0        697.0           150.0       356.0       114.0         2.5568             77100.0          INLAND
20637    -121.22     39.43                17.0       2254.0           485.0      1007.0       433.0         1.7000             92300.0          INLAND
20638    -121.32     39.43                18.0       1860.0           409.0       741.0       349.0         1.8672             84700.0          INLAND
20639    -121.24     39.37                16.0       2785.0           616.0      1387.0       530.0         2.3886             89400.0          INLAND

[20640 rows x 10 columns]
```

Comment: все получилось, спасибо большое!